# Add Object to an NSMutableArray that is an element of an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

In the code below, I declare an NSDictionary and fill it with empty NSMutableArrays designated by numeric keys:

```
NSDictionary *result = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
for(float i = 0; i < 120; i += 0.25){
    [result setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", i]];
}
```

Now if I have an object I want to add to one of the arrays and the key of the array I want to add it to (for example if I want to add a string to the array with key 4.25), how do I add the object to that array?

Comment: 1) You need an `NSMutableDictionary`. 2) Don't use `setValue:forKey:` to add a key/value pair to a dictionary. Use `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[result[@"4.25"] addObject: @"aString"];
```

Note that your code won't work as written. You need to create your dictionary as mutable if you are going to add key/value pairs to it after it's created.